# Unwanted android permission

Tags: android, android-permissions

My app is using only the following permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

But when I install my app it asks for an unknown permission:

> modify or delete the contents of your USB storage read the contents of your USB storage

Following is my build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.plusgaurav.weatherballoon"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

repositories {
maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
// support libraries
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.0'
// google play services location api
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:7.5.0'
// making connection requests
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0'
// animation
compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
compile 'com.daimajia.easing:library:1.0.1@aar'
compile 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:1.1.3@aar'
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What permissions are you seeing? The library most likely bringing in the permission is `com.google.android.gms:play-services-location`.

Comment: modify or delete the contents of your USB storage read the contents of your USB storage when I install the app via the generated apk. I was also getting contacts permission when I was using the whole gms library, so I put a specific one instead.

Comment: @JaredBurrows You were right. I read up with the possible duplicate of this question and it seems that it is a known issue with gms 7.5. I have accepted that it is a duplicate question and the other users having the same doubt will be redirected there. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google play services 7.5 add other permissions, it's normal. If you try to include for example all the play services (you are now including only the location part) you will see a lot of new permissions as well.